# React + MaterialUI Menu bounces layout 15px to the left in the presence of a vertical scroll bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, menu, scrollbar

I implemented a Material-UI vertical menu in my application.  It works fine on the absence of a vertical scroll bar.
[image: Before]

But when a vertical scroll bar is on, the vertical menu bounces the layout like 15px to the left, leaving an undesirable vertical blank space, next to the scroll bar.

[image: After]

I'm using @mui/material 5.0.6 and react 17.0.2

Here's my vertical menu code (inspired from the mui documentation)

```
import React from "react";
import { Divider, IconButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText,Menu, MenuItem} from "@mui/material";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import GroupsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Groups';
import PointOfSaleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PointOfSale';
import ReceiptIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Receipt';
import PriceCheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PriceCheck';
import LocalPlayIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalPlay';
import EmojiEventsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmojiEvents';
import DirectionsRunIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DirectionsRun';
import SellIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Sell';
import Inventory2Icon from '@mui/icons-material/Inventory2';
import UploadFileIcon from '@mui/icons-material/UploadFile';
import DriveFileRenameOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DriveFileRenameOutline';

export const AppMenu = () => {
   
   const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

   const navigate = useNavigate();
 
   const handleMenu = (event) => {
     setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
   };
 
   const handleClose = () => {
     setAnchorEl(null);
   };

   const handleMenuClick = (page) => {
      navigate(page);
      setAnchorEl(null);
   }

return (
    <div>
        <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
            onClick={handleMenu}
        >
            <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
            id="menu-appbar"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
            MenuListProps={{
                "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
            }}

            keepMounted
        variant="menu"
            
        >
            
        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/home')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <HomeIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Inicio</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>            
        <Divider />
        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/loadData')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <UploadFileIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Carga de datos</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem> 

        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/clientList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <GroupsIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Clientes</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>  

        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/billsList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <ReceiptIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Facturas</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>   

        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/parameterGroupsList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <Inventory2Icon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Grupos de parámetros</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>              

        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/movementList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <DirectionsRunIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Movimientos</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>  

        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/benefitsList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <EmojiEventsIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Nivel de beneficios</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>               

        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/referenceProgramList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <LocalPlayIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Programas de referenciación </ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>              
        
        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/promotionsList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <PriceCheckIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Promociones / Exclusiones </ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>            

        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/salesPointList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <PointOfSaleIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Puntos de venta</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>    

        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/redemptionsList')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <SellIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Redenciones</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>                
      
        <MenuItem onClick={() => {handleMenuClick('/recordMovement')}}>
           <ListItemIcon>
              <DriveFileRenameOutlineIcon color="primary" fontSize="medium"/>
           </ListItemIcon>          
           <ListItemText>Registrar movimientos</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>                
      
        
        </Menu>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Does anyone have similar behaviour?.  How did you solve it?.  **Note**: i already tried to use a Popper version, but it was worst.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it

Just added:

```
disableScrollLock={true}
```

to the Menu component properties and it made the magic

Answer (score 0):

mui [menu](https://mui.com/zh/material-ui/api/menu/) component is override on [popover](https://mui.com/zh/material-ui/api/popover/), in popover, set marginThreshold={0} can disable this feature, this api has not supported in menu's api yet, can use popover+list instead

```
        <Popover
        // id={id}
        open={open}
        marginThreshold={0}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'left',
        }}>
        <List>
            {menu.submenu.map((v, i) =>
                v.type === "separator" ? <Divider key={i} sx={{my: 0.5}}/> :
                    v.submenu ? <Submenu menu={v}/> :
                        <ListItemButton key={i} onClick={v.click || handleClose}>
                            {v.label}
                        </ListItemButton>
            )}
        </List>
    </Popover>
```